# Reusing an answer's image after editing in another post on a different Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, images, copyright, attribution, content-reuse

I would like to download an image from [this answer on Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144964) (linking to imgur), edit it and use it in a post on another site of Stack Exchange in a question. (Basically I want this nice cube frame with additional annotation.)

Is this OK with regards to copyright if I link to the original post for reference? What else would I have to do?

Comment: Thank you for caring & asking about licensing. This is not as common as it should be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just provide attribution. Jeff provided some [guidance](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) on what that means which is basically...

Generally a link back to where you found it and the name of the author of the original work is enough.

There's no copyright issue because as long as you follow the attribution requirements, the content on Stack Exchange is licenced in a way that you can use it elsewhere.

Note that this applies whether you use the image elsewhere on Stack Exchange or somewhere completely different.